# AWS EC2 access to S3 with IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

Scenario: I have an EC2 instance and a S3 bucket under the same account, and my web app on that EC2 wants access to resources in that bucket.

Following official docs, I created an IAM role with `s3access` and assigned it to the EC2 instance. To my understanding, now my web app should be able to access the bucket. However, after trials, seems I have to add a `allowPublicRead` bucket policy like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Otherwise I got access forbidden.

But why should I use this `allowPublicRead` bucket policy, since I already granted `s3access` IAM role to the EC2 instance?

Comment: @stanely-luo, probably you wanna look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57476893?noredirect=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 `s3:GetObject` will only allow access to objects from your ec2 instance and what you want is to access these objects from your web-app which means from your browser, in this case these images/objects will be rendered to user browser and if its a public facing application then you need to assign `AllowPublicRead` permission as well.

Comment: Thanks! One more question, if it's just client talk to S3 directly, why do we need to assign IAM role with `s3access` to EC2?

Comment: yes as your code is deployed to ec2 machine and it needs to connect to S3 to get the object and then send it back to client. So ec2  needs to have S3 access.

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal, say the s3 resource is an image as an link in the webpage. So here, CORS comes in to action. So if CORS and Public access for the resource are enabled for the Bucket, that should do. And when public access is already granted, what's the point in adding a role to EC2 instance, the resource is already public. So, is not the role redundant and not necessary

Comment: @samshers, I need to check on this, would get back to you on this.

Comment: NP, it's answered here by @John-Rotenstein. Hope it help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57476893?noredirect=1